# Is a new JSF session started when a new Spring Security login session starts?

Tags: spring, jsf, session, spring-security

I'm in Mojarra 2.1.29, Tomcat 7 and Spring security 2.0. I'm a little confused about the concept of session. It's a well-known fact that managed bean that are session scoped are being creted once per session. My question is is the spring security session the same as JSF session or they are running in the different ways?

For instance, we're sending a login request from already authorized user. What's going to happen with the sessions.

I presume, we start a new Spring security session. But is a new JSF session going to be started too?

Answer (score 1):

Both, spring-security session and jsf session is bound to the http session from servlet container. In spring-security you can configure with session-fixation in which case an new http session is created.
@See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-session-fixation
@See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sessionauthenticationstrategy

JSF itself also stores session scoped managed beans as an attribute of the HttpSession.

By default spring-security has 'migrate' session. In this case the jsf session will continue. when 'newSession' is set, a clean session will be created without current jsf session.

Comment: If you provide some references, I'll give you a +1 ;-)